# Environment (in module jdk.compiler) because module jdk.compiler does not export com.sun.tools.javac.processing to unnamed module

Tags: java

I want to using GraalVM in my Spring Boot 2.3.10.RELEASE project because it can decrease the memory usage of JVM(Now I am using JDK 11), so I add the dependencies:

```
api "org.springframework.experimental:spring-native:0.10.2"
```

add the gradle plugin:

```
apply plugin: "com.github.ayltai.spring-graalvm-native-plugin"
```

add native build config:

```
nativeImage {
        mainClassName              = 'com.dolphin.soa.manage.AppStarter'
        traceClassInitialization   = true
        reportExceptionStackTraces = true
        removeUnusedAutoConfig     = true
        removeYamlSupport          = true
        removeSpelSupport          = true
        removeJmxSupport           = true
        maxHeapSize                = '4G'
}
```

finnaly I am using this Gradle(7.0) command to build a native jar:

```
./gradlew clean :dolphin-manage:dolphin-manage-service:bootBuildImage -x test
```

but show this error:

```
> Configure project :dolphin-acientbay
/Users/dolphin/source/retire
> Configure project :dolphin-post
/Users/dolphin/source/retire
> Configure project :dolphin-template
/Users/dolphin/source/retire
> Task :dolphin-common:compileJava FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':dolphin-common:compileJava'.
> java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class lombok.javac.apt.LombokProcessor (in unnamed module @0x2155f75f) cannot access class com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment (in module jdk.compiler) because module jdk.compiler does not export com.sun.tools.javac.processing to unnamed module @0x2155f75f

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 6m 49s
5 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 4 up-to-date
(base)
```

is it a compatible problem about GraalVM and lombok? is it possible to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I'm seeing this same type of error running spotless on my Java project. I just reported a bug about this to them: https://github.com/diffplug/spotless/issues/1244

I diagnosed the problem as some kind behavioral change between Java 15 and Java 16. So one thing you can do is revert to an earlier version of Java to see if that makes the issue go away. If it does, you should report a bug similar to what I did to the project with the problem so they can try to fix it.